# Generate a sequence of records from a base record

Tags: missing-data, create-table, union-all, dolphindb, cross-join

Is there a way to expand table 1 into table 2? It is to output each integer between start_no and end_no as a seq_no field, and take the other fields of the original table to form a new table (table 2).

Table 1:

```
date       source market channel_no start_no end_no err_type
---------- ------ ------ ---------- -------- ------ --------
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       565663   565665 1       
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       565918   565920 1       
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       566010   566012 1       
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       566363   566365 1       
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       566512   566513 1
```

Table 2:

```
date       source market channel_no err_type seq_no
---------- ------ ------ ---------- -------- ------
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565663
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565664
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565665
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565918
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565919
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565920
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566010
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566011
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566012
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566363
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566364
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566365
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566512
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566513
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `each` and `cj(cross join)`  to loop through each row of original table and conduct cross join with the sequence data table generated by `start_no` and `end_no`, where the cross join returns the Cartesian product of rows from the tables in the join. In the end, you use `function unionAll` to combine all the intermediate tables into the final output table.

The simulated data, the algorithm, and the results are listed as follows:

Simulated data:

```
start_no=[565663,565918,566010,566363,566512]
end_no=[565665,565920,566012,566365,566513]
tb=table(take(2022.06.01,5) as date,take(`src55,5) as source,take(`SZ,5) as market,take(2011,5) as channel_no,start_no  , end_no,take(1,5) as err_type);

tb;
date       source market channel_no start_no end_no err_type
---------- ------ ------ ---------- -------- ------ --------
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       565663   565665 1
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       565918   565920 1
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       566010   566012 1
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       566363   566365 1
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       566512   566513 1
```

The algorithm:

```
def f(tb,i){
        tt=select date,source,market,channel_no,err_type from tb where rowNo(date)=i
        start_no=tb[i]['start_no']
        end_no=tb[i]['end_no']
        return cj(tt,table(start_no..end_no as seq_no))
        }
tb=unionAll(each(f{tb},1..size(tb)-1),false)
```

Results：

```
date       source market channel_no err_type seq_no
---------- ------ ------ ---------- -------- ------
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565663
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565664
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565665
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565918
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565919
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        565920
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566010
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566011
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566012
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566363
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566364
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566365
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566512
2022.06.01 src55  SZ     2011       1        566513
```